# How to use 'start' cmd with arguments and correct syntax via psexec?

Tags: psexec

Via psexec, I can execute the following command on a remote windows machine:

```
start notepad "c:\hello.txt" & exit
```

But I cannot run:

```
start "c:\progra~2\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome" playboy.com
```

Windows says it cannot find playboy.com

In total though, I would like to run the following command via psexec:

```
start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" playboy.com & exit
```

Comment: Or you could just `start "" "http://www.playboy.com"` and let the browser the user has configured handle it, rather than hard-coding Chrome. The reason your second command fails is because the quoted string is interpreted as the window title, which you're not interested in here. As an aside, popping up a website on a remote machine is either a bad way to solve a software problem, or not the most appropriate prank one can come up with.

Comment: Thanks... It was just an example I happened upon that was causing an issue, rather than a prank. Including "" after start solved the problem! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As Jereon detailed, include "" for the window title after using start. Then if including path within quotes, followed by arguments, the command works fine.